Export multiple named meshes to Wavefront OBJ
When using Export to .obj for two line elements
With[{g1 = Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 4}}], g2 = Line[{{3, 3, 3}, {5, 5, 5}}]},
 {Show[Graphics3D@{g1, g2}],
  Export["path/twoOBJECTS06.obj", Show[Graphics3D@{g1, g2}]]}]

both lines are added to the same # Mesh ' ' without name and assigned the same DefaultMaterial like
# Created with the Wolfram Language : www.wolfram.com

mtllib twoOBJECTS06.mtl

# 4 vertex positions
v  0 0 0
v  1 2 4
v  3 3 3
v  5 5 5

# 0 UV coordinates

# 0 vertex normals

# Mesh '' with 2 faces
usemtl DefaultMaterial
l  1 2
l  3 4

How can I tell Export to create separate meshes with distinct materials?
# Created with the Wolfram Language : www.wolfram.com

mtllib twoOBJECTS06.mtl

# 4 vertex positions
v  0 0 0
v  1 2 4
v  3 3 3
v  5 5 5

# 0 UV coordinates

# 0 vertex normals

# Mesh 'line1' with 1 faces
usemtl MaterialLine1
l  1 2

# Mesh 'line2' with 1 faces
usemtl MaterialLine2
l  3 4

(Show and Graphics3D is nested because later I wish to add multiple objects)
